# How to save and restore fragment state that involves dragging and dropping elements? (Android Studio - Java)

Tags: java, android, android-studio, android-fragments, drag-and-drop

I have a HomeFragment that allows the user to drag and drop certain elements around, and I want to be able to that when you switch back to this fragment that the elements are still in their new positions after they have been dragged and dropped, and that their positions aren't resetted when you switch back to the HomeFragment. I'm not sure if getSharedPreferences would be used here since the user could be frequently moving the elements around.

Here is the HomeFragment.java and then the MainActivity.java

```
package loon.si.weather_app;

import android.content.ClipData;
import android.content.ClipDescription;
import android.graphics.Color;
import android.graphics.PorterDuff;
import android.os.Bundle;

import androidx.annotation.NonNull;
import androidx.fragment.app.Fragment;

import android.util.Log;
import android.view.DragEvent;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.LinearLayout;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.google.android.material.navigation.NavigationView;

public class HomeFragment extends Fragment implements View.OnDragListener, View.OnLongClickListener {

//    private static final String DRAGGED_STATE = "string";
    TextView txtVw;
    ImageView imgVw;
    Button btn;

//    float x_pos;
//    float y_pos;

    @Override
    public boolean onLongClick(View v) {
        // Create a new ClipData.Item from the ImageView object's tag
        ClipData.Item item = new ClipData.Item((CharSequence) v.getTag());
        // Create a new ClipData using the tag as a label, the plain text MIME type, and
        // the already-created item. This will create a new ClipDescription object within the
        // ClipData, and set its MIME type entry to "text/plain"
        String[] mimeTypes = {ClipDescription.MIMETYPE_TEXT_PLAIN};
        ClipData data = new ClipData(v.getTag().toString(), mimeTypes, item);
        // Instantiates the drag shadow builder.
        View.DragShadowBuilder dragshadow = new View.DragShadowBuilder(v);
        // Starts the drag
        v.startDragAndDrop(data        // data to be dragged
                , dragshadow   // drag shadow builder
                , v           // local data about the drag and drop operation
                , 0          // flags (not currently used, set to 0)
        );
        return true;
    }

    // This is the method that the system calls when it dispatches a drag event to the listener.
    @Override
    public boolean onDrag(View v, DragEvent event) {
        // Defines a variable to store the action type for the incoming event
        int action = event.getAction();
        // Handles each of the expected events
        switch (action) {

            case DragEvent.ACTION_DRAG_STARTED:
                // Determines if this View can accept the dragged data
                if (event.getClipDescription().hasMimeType(ClipDescription.MIMETYPE_TEXT_PLAIN)) {
                    // if you want to apply color when drag started to your view you can uncomment below lines
                    // to give any color tint to the View to indicate that it can accept data.
                    // v.getBackground().setColorFilter(Color.BLUE, PorterDuff.Mode.SRC_IN);
                    // Invalidate the view to force a redraw in the new tint
                    //  v.invalidate();
                    // returns true to indicate that the View can accept the dragged data.
                    return true;
                }
                // Returns false. During the current drag and drop operation, this View will
                // not receive events again until ACTION_DRAG_ENDED is sent.
                return false;

            case DragEvent.ACTION_DRAG_ENTERED:
                // Applies a GRAY or any color tint to the View. Return true; the return value is ignored.
                v.getBackground().setColorFilter(Color.GRAY, PorterDuff.Mode.SRC_IN);
                // Invalidate the view to force a redraw in the new tint
                v.invalidate();
                return true;

            case DragEvent.ACTION_DRAG_LOCATION:
                // Ignore the event
                return true;

            case DragEvent.ACTION_DRAG_EXITED:
                // Re-sets the color tint to blue. Returns true; the return value is ignored.
                // view.getBackground().setColorFilter(Color.BLUE, PorterDuff.Mode.SRC_IN);
                //It will clear a color filter .
                v.getBackground().clearColorFilter();
                // Invalidate the view to force a redraw in the new tint
                v.invalidate();
                return true;

            case DragEvent.ACTION_DROP:
                // Gets the item containing the dragged data
                ClipData.Item item = event.getClipData().getItemAt(0);
                // Gets the text data from the item.
                String dragData = item.getText().toString();
                // Displays a message containing the dragged data.
                Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Dragged data is " + dragData, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                // Turns off any color tints
                v.getBackground().clearColorFilter();
                // Invalidates the view to force a redraw
                v.invalidate();

                View vw = (View) event.getLocalState();
                ViewGroup owner = (ViewGroup) vw.getParent();
                owner.removeView(vw); //remove the dragged view
                //caste the view into LinearLayout as our drag acceptable layout is LinearLayout
                LinearLayout container = (LinearLayout) v;
                container.addView(vw);//Add the dragged view
                vw.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);//finally set Visibility to VISIBLE
                // Returns true. DragEvent.getResult() will return true.
                return true;

            case DragEvent.ACTION_DRAG_ENDED:
                // Turns off any color tinting
                v.getBackground().clearColorFilter();
                // Invalidates the view to force a redraw
                v.invalidate();
                // Does a getResult(), and displays what happened.
                if (event.getResult())
                    Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "The drop was handled.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                else
                    Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "The drop didn't work.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
//                x_pos = event.getX();
//                y_pos = event.getY();
                // returns true; the value is ignored.
                return true;
            // An unknown action type was received.
            default:
                Log.e("DragDrop Example", "Unknown action type received by OnDragListener.");
                break;
        }
        return false;
    }
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // Inflate the layout for this fragment
        View viewFragment = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_home, container, false);

        txtVw = viewFragment.findViewById(R.id.lbl);
        txtVw.setTag("DRAGGABLE TEXTVIEW");
        txtVw.setOnLongClickListener(this);

        imgVw = viewFragment.findViewById(R.id.ingvw);
        imgVw.setTag("ANDROID ICON");
        imgVw.setOnLongClickListener(this);

        btn = viewFragment.findViewById(R.id.btnDrag);
        btn.setTag("DRAGGABLE BUTTON");
        btn.setOnLongClickListener(this);

        //Set Drag Event Listeners for defined layouts
        viewFragment.findViewById(R.id.layout1).setOnDragListener(this);
        viewFragment.findViewById(R.id.layout2).setOnDragListener(this);
        viewFragment.findViewById(R.id.layout3).setOnDragListener(this);

//        if (savedInstanceState != null) {
//            // Restore last state for checked position.
//            boolean clickable = savedInstanceState.getBoolean(DRAGGED_STATE, false);
//            btn.setX(x_pos);
//            btn.setY(y_pos);
//        }

        return viewFragment;
    }

//    @Override
//    public void onSaveInstanceState(@NonNull Bundle savedInstanceState) {
//        super.onSaveInstanceState(savedInstanceState);
//        savedInstanceState.putBoolean(DRAGGED_STATE, btn.isClickable() );
//    }

}
```

```
package loon.si.weather_app;

import androidx.annotation.NonNull;
import androidx.appcompat.app.ActionBarDrawerToggle;
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;
import androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar;
import androidx.core.view.GravityCompat;
import androidx.drawerlayout.widget.DrawerLayout;
import androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManager;
import android.annotation.SuppressLint;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.google.android.material.navigation.NavigationView;
import java.util.Objects;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements NavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener {
    private WidgetFragment widgetFragment;
//    private HomeFragment homeFragment;
    private final String WIDGET_FRAGMENT_TAG = "widgetfragmenttag";
//    private final String HOME_FRAGMENT_TAG = "homefragmenttag";
    private DrawerLayout drawerLayout;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        Toolbar toolbar = findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
        
        drawerLayout = findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
        NavigationView navigationView = findViewById(R.id.nav_view);
        navigationView.setNavigationItemSelectedListener(this);

        ActionBarDrawerToggle toggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(this, drawerLayout, toolbar, R.string.open_nav, R.string.close_nav);

        drawerLayout.addDrawerListener(toggle);
        toggle.syncState();

//        if (savedInstanceState == null) {
//            getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
//                    .replace(R.id.fragment_container, new HomeFragment()).commit();
//            navigationView.setCheckedItem(R.id.nav_home);
//        }

        if (savedInstanceState != null) { // saved instance state, fragment may exist
            // look up the instance that already exists by tag
            widgetFragment = (WidgetFragment)
                    getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentByTag(WIDGET_FRAGMENT_TAG);
        } else if (widgetFragment == null) {
            // only create fragment if they haven't been instantiated already
            widgetFragment = new WidgetFragment();
        }

//        if (savedInstanceState != null) { // saved instance state, fragment may exist
//            // look up the instance that already exists by tag
//            homeFragment = (HomeFragment)
//                    getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentByTag(HOME_FRAGMENT_TAG);
//            widgetFragment = (WidgetFragment)
//                    getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentByTag(WIDGET_FRAGMENT_TAG);
//        } else if (homeFragment == null) {
//            // only create fragment if they haven't been instantiated already
//            homeFragment = new HomeFragment();
//        } else if (widgetFragment == null) {
//            // only create fragment if they haven't been instantiated already
//            widgetFragment = new WidgetFragment();
//        }
    }

    @SuppressLint("NonConstantResourceId")
    @Override
    public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(@NonNull MenuItem item) {
        switch (item.getItemId()){
            case R.id.nav_home:
                getSupportFragmentManager().
                        beginTransaction().
                        replace(R.id.fragment_container,
                                new HomeFragment()).
                        commit();
                break;

            case R.id.nav_settings:
                getSupportFragmentManager().
                        beginTransaction().
                        replace(R.id.fragment_container,
                                new SettingsFragment()).
                        commit();
                break;

            case R.id.nav_widget:
                getSupportFragmentManager().
                        beginTransaction().
                        replace(R.id.fragment_container,
                                widgetFragment, WIDGET_FRAGMENT_TAG).
                        commit();
                break;

            case R.id.nav_location:
                getSupportFragmentManager().
                        beginTransaction().
                        replace(R.id.fragment_container,
                                new LocationFragment()).
                        commit();
                break;

            case R.id.fragment_temp_api_demo:
                getSupportFragmentManager().
                        beginTransaction().
                        replace(R.id.fragment_container,
                                new TempApiDemoFragment()).
                        commit();
                break;

            case R.id.nav_education:
                getSupportFragmentManager().
                        beginTransaction().
                        replace(R.id.fragment_container,
                                new EducationFragment()).
                        commit();
                break;

            case R.id.nav_shopping:
            getSupportFragmentManager().
                    beginTransaction().
                    replace(R.id.fragment_container,
                            new ShoppingFragment()).
                    commit();
            break;

            case R.id.nav_logout:
                Toast.makeText(this, "Logout Button Pressed",
                        Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).
                        show();
                break;
        }
        drawerLayout.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public void onBackPressed() {
        if (drawerLayout.isDrawerOpen(GravityCompat.START)){
            drawerLayout.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
        } else {
            super.onBackPressed();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You're creating a brand new `HomeFragment` in your `onNavigationItemSelected`. How is that ever going to have anything to do with the state of the previous fragment instance that you completely replaced and threw away? Are you looking for help with how your MainActivity swaps fragments or how your individual fragment should be [saving its state](https://developer.android.com/guide/fragments/saving-state) across configuration changes and process death and recreation? Because those are two completely separate problems.

Comment: @ianhanniballake, the second part of your statement. I was going to change the replace in the onNavigationItemSelected for the home fragment to be like the widgetFragment one.

Comment: Oh, because that `widgetFragment` approach won't work either (when you `replace()`, you're still throwing away all of the state the FragmentManager is saving for you). It looks like you've already tried using `savedInstanceState`, which would be enough to handle things like rotating your device while on that fragment. What actually happened (since I assume that code wasn't enough if you're asking this question about saving state across config changes)?

Comment: @ianhanniballake So the widgetFragment just has a checkbox and I was able to get that fragment to save its state so it remembers if you checked the checkbox or not when switching the fragments. I was trying to do the same idea but for the homeFragment but that has elements that you drag and drop around and Im not sure how save the state of where all the elements are positioned and such. As you can tell, the commented out lines of code is me trying to do that and trying to incorporate it in MainActivity which definitely isnt working